# System.import returns empty object

Tags: javascript, webpack, systemjs

I have a simple module to play with SystemJS and dynamic module loading in javascript:

```
export default function test() {
    alert('test');
}
```

That file is processed with my webpack configuration to the following (am I right that is what is called "module"?):

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };

/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };

/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };

/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 445);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ 445:
/***/ function(module, exports) {

"use strict";
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.default = test;
function test() {
    alert('test');
}

/***/ }

/******/ });
```

I have made that file accessible from my web application:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/test
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:2672
Date:Sun, 01 Jan 2017 16:34:54 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/x-es-module, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=ac781d41-fdd4-4bae-9290-e54e960dfa8d; JSESSIONID=57B0C1DDA88DE1D6D4031CC8BCBCCBC9
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Then I added `<script src="js/system.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` inside a page `<head>` tag, and write in console:

```
SystemJS.import('./test').then(m => console.log(m))
```

which downloads file(I see it through browser dev tools) but outputs empty object into console. Neither `m.default` or `m.test` returs anything except undefined.

**I expect to be able to call `test` after importing, what I do wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack uses `System.import` rather than `SystemJS.import`. Additionally if you are using the latest webpack RC, we are now recommending you use the native spec `import()` instead.

Here's an example from our github repo on how to use it. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/examples/code-splitting-harmony/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Seems like it requires all possible candidates to be processed with wepack(my test.js module became 0.bundle.js). Then when I do import it downloads the module from /0.bundle.js. Thats clear now. But what if I want not to expose all my modules and import them from custom URL, doing some server logic e.g. access check? Is it possible?

Comment: You could use publicPath and set a CDN URL. If that's what you mean.

Comment: Right, publicPath allows me to set URL where it dynamically loads chunks from. But I can't identify what source .js file it corresponds: `test.js` became `0.bundle.js`. How could I figure out what was the original source file?

Comment: Ahhhh you want to be able to use `named chunks`. Okay so because of the limitation of the loader spec, there isn't a way to do this out of the box via webpack. So if you would like to have chunk names you would want to use `require.ensure`

Comment: Could you please provide some example? I tried `require.ensure` example from [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) but the output chunk name was still 0.bundle.js.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-require/ Here is a guide, to get the named chunks I believe you can do output.chunkfilename = `[name].chunk.js`;